# Question about the MATLAB gravity models

Tags: newtonian-gravity, computational-physics, geophysics

There is a graph showing the gravity values as a function of latitudes for point mass, zonal harmonic, and wgs84 gravity models at [Comparing Zonal Harmonic Gravity Model to Other Gravity Models](https://www.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/comparing-zonal-harmonic-gravity-model-to-other-gravity-models.html).  The point mass model should be constant but it's not.  Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that these are all evaluated the "surface" of the Earth?  The Earth's not a sphere so with the point mass assumption your distance would vary and hence the acceleration.

Comment: You're right .... "This example shows how to examine the zonal harmonic, spherical, and 1984 World Geodetic System (WGS84) gravity models for latitudes from +/- 90 degrees at the surface of the Earth."  I did miss something.  I'll withdraw the question.  But then, what is 'down' gravity, as the down direction on an oblate spheroid doesn't always point to the center of the earth?

Comment: The caption on the graph above is "Figure 1: Gravity in the Down-axis in meters per second squared".  What is 'down' axis, as the down direction on an oblate spheroid doesn't always point to the center of the earth?  There is another graph showing the north component of gravity for each model, and the graph is flat 0 for the point mass model, implying that the down axis does point to the center of the earth.